# ajax/php on click submit form redirect but execute send.php

Tags: php, ajax, forms

(sorry for my english its not my native language)

simple question,
can i execute php file to deal with form data (including files) but redirect user without waiting for response from my send.php file?

there are a lot of file uploading in my php process which means a lot of waiting time to complete. i dont want the user to wait that long...

at the moment im using ajax to prevent the user from redirecting to send.php which make php execute but the user is still waiting until the "success" function invoked after the file uploading and php is finished, which again means user wait forever ...redirecting before success function prevent the php from finishing.

what i want is that the second the user click submit, launch send.php in the background and redirect the user to another page, without even waiting for response from the send.php file.

in my php i check for errors and deal with that so the user dont even need to know  of any errors.

(btw everything is working just not happy with the procces)

my ajax:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                 $.ajax({            
                    url: $('#myForm').prop('action'),
                    type: $(this).attr('method'),
                    data: new FormData($('#myForm')[0]),
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('Form submitted');
                        window.location = "http://www.somesite.com/";
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        // The request failed - So something here
                        alert('Form NOT submitted'); //display an alert whether the form is
                        console.log('form not submited ERROR');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must wait until the file is uploaded.
After the upload is finished you could start a background proccess (thread), for example if you have to manipulate the upload.
But thread handling is not possible with PHP.

Comment: thnx for your comment. so there is no way to redirect ,exec the php without waiting for response?

Comment: You could run a background proccess, eg: [link](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2007/01/12/running-a-background-process-in-php/)
But if you are uploading files you have to wait until the files are uploaded to the server, because if you redirecting before the upload is finished the upload would be interupted

Comment: thanx again @ghovat